# Update column based on value in previous row plus values in current row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to calculate the new qty on hand based on the previous row's new quantity on hand plus the current row's receipts minus the current rows issued.  Then for the next row repeat the process.  I want reset based on item_no, and loc.

Below is the code to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[zItemLocDailyAvgCost]
(
    [ID] [numeric] (9,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [item_no] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [loc] [nchar] (3) NOT NULL,
    [trx_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [qty_lock] [int] NULL,
    [orig_qty_on_hand] [decimal](13, 4) NULL,
    [qty_received] [decimal](13, 4) NULL,
    [unit_cost_received] [decimal] (16, 6) NULL,
    [qty_issued] [decimal](13, 4) NULL,
    [new_qty_on_hand] [decimal](13, 4) NULL,
    [avg_cost] [decimal](16, 6) NULL
) [ON PRIMARY]
```

I also have a primary index on item_no, loc and trx_dt with the date descending.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [zItemLocDailyAvgCost0] 
ON [dbo].[zItemLocDailyAvgCost] ([item_no] ASC, [loc] ASC, [trx_dt] DESC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
               SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
               DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO`
```

I've populated the table with the new_qty_on_hand value for "today" and then want to work backwards to calculate yesterday's on hand based on today's on hand plus yesterday's receipts minus yesterday's issued.  Then store the value in yesterday's new_qty_on_hand column and repeat the process.  I also want to reset this process when the item_no and loc combination change.

I tried the CTE below and it would work for the first record but then come up with incorrect values beyond that.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY z.item_no asc, z.loc asc, z.trx_dt desc),
  z.item_no
, z.loc
, z.trx_dt
, z.qty_lock
, z.orig_qty_on_hand
, z.new_qty_on_hand
, z.qty_issued
, z.qty_received
FROM zItemLocDailyAvgCost z
)
UPDATE CTE
SET new_qty_on_hand = case when CTE.qty_lock = 0 then prev.new_qty_on_hand + CTE.qty_received - CTE.qty_issued
else CTE.new_qty_on_hand end
, orig_qty_on_hand = prev.new_qty_on_hand
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
GO`
```

Here is the output I get with the code above.

```
ID    item_no   loc    trx_dt        qty_lock  orig_qty_on_hand  qty_received   unit_cost_received    qty_issued    new_qty_on_hand    avg_cost
636   200001    XYZ    2016-05-28     1        NULL              0.0000         0.000000              75183.0004    552939.1530        0.110000
635   200001    XYZ    2016-05-27     0        552939.1530       635262.0000    0.110000              210379.8339   977821.3191        0.000000
634   200001    XYZ    2016-05-26     0        0.0000            176400.0000    0.110000              143545.8339   32854.1661         0.000000
633   200001    XYZ    2016-05-25     0        0.0000            235200.0000    0.110000              253137.0006   -17937.0006        0.000000
```

Once the values are populated I will update "today" going forward separately so this is really a one-time process.

Thank you,

Kevin

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem correctly. Yet, it would seem to me that you might be interested in the following post if you have an SQL 2012 (or later) server available instead of the 2008 R2 you are currently working on: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: Ralph, thank you.  Both the QA and production servers are 2008 R2 however.

Comment: Here's an article with several 2008R2 solutions (since you don't have LEAD and LAG) http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/ Hope it's of use.